# Selecting multi attributes in scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'm trying to fetch some data from the page using scrapy. Let's say there html:

```
<div class=example id=example>
<p>Some text</p>
<ul>
<li>A list 1</li>
<li>A list 2</li>
<li>A list 3</li>
</ul>
<p>text again</p>
</div>
```

I'm selecting this data by selecting whole id and then axtracting the data by attributes, like this:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="example"]/p').getall()
```

The result is:

```
<p>Some text</p>
 <p>text again</p>
```

But I can't get the list.
I would like to get this:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<ul>
<li>A list 1</li>
<li>A list 2</li>
<li>A list 3</li>
</ul>
<p>text again</p>
```

Any suggestions how should I get all the attributes and data inside this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
lst = response.xpath('//div[@id="example"]/*').getall()
```

will return what you want:

```
lst = ['<p>Some text</p>', '<ul>\r\n<li>A list 1</li>\r\n<li>A list 2</li>\r\n<li>A list 3</li>\r\n</ul>', '<p>text again</p>']
```

Let's print the list in order:

```
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

```
<p>Some text</p>
<ul>
<li>A list 1</li>
<li>A list 2</li>
<li>A list 3</li>
</ul>
<p>text again</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
 response.xpath('//*[@id="example"]/p | //*[@id="example"]/p /ul/li').getall()
```

Comment: This gives back all ul's on the page not only in this div that I needed. And if I use /ul instead of //ul no ul's comeback.

Comment: Now, updated and try again and let me know. Thanks

Comment: response.xpath('//*[@id="example"]/p | //*[@id="example"]/p /ul/li').getall() - nop, but:
 response.xpath('//*[@id="example"]/p | //*[@id="example"]/ul/li').getall() - works almost fine.